# php key count of multidimetional array

Tags: php

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => bottom wear
            [1] => 1
            [2] => jeans
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 677
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => top wear
        [1] => 1
        [2] => tshirt
        [3] => 3
        [4] => 450
    )
```

)

Wants the count of first array i.e 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function.

```
$size = count($arr[0]);
```